# Fix indentation in a file while keeping cursor on the same line

Tags: indentation, cursor, indent

I'd like to use vim's builtin indent fix feature on an entire file. I have looked up answers, but all I found were suggestions to type `gg=G`, the only problem being that it brings your cursor to the top of the file.

How could I easily indent a whole file without changing my cursor's position?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All "long" jump commands, such as `gg`, automatically save the bookmark for the previous poisition (note that `G` here is a "motion", so it does not overwrite the bookmark again), so all you have to do is to go back by that bookmark with two backticks:

```
nnoremap <leader>= gg=G``
```

Or you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> to navigate through the jumplist (`:h jumplist`) to and fro.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to dedicate a keybinding to it (let's say `\G` for concreteness), then it's possible to set a mark and return to it in your keybinding.

```
nnoremap \G mpgg=G`p
```

`mp` set mark. A lowercase letter means that mark is associated with the current buffer. The mark `P` is universal, `p` is not.

`gg=G` move to the top of the buffer and indent down to the bottom, as you mentioned in the question.

`` `p `` return to the mark.

This solution is not ideal because your cursor might still jump around because of things like `scrolloff`, but it does minimize how visually distracting it is to re-indent a file fairly well in practice.