# Yank then Paste without moving cursor

Tags: cut-copy-paste, normal-mode, cursor

I want to be able to:

```
:42y
```

then something like:

```
:13p
```

having it to paste the yanked line in a new line after 13, without taking my cursor away. So far, all solutions I have found involves going to the paste region, as calling

```
:13<ENTER>p
```

(or similar) - but then loosing the cursor position.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fix indentation in a file while keeping cursor on the same line](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/21582/fix-indentation-in-a-file-while-keeping-cursor-on-the-same-line)

Comment: There are definitely versions of this question elsewhere. Hmm.

Comment: @Matt, that is what I don't want: to move on then move back. Since I am able to yank without changing position, I would also like to paste.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define your special version of "put" like this:

```
command! -bar -bang -range -register Put call append(<line2> - <bang>0, getreg(<q-reg>, 1, 1))
```

Now `13Pu` works without any jumping around.

Comment: It worked like a charm, because it IS a charm. Would you please expand on what this is doing?

Comment: @fde-capu Read `:h :command`, `:h append()` and `:h getreg()`. Basically, it's a new command which takes parameters (almost) like a regular `:put`, but calls `append()` to do the job. Of course, you can also call `append()` directly, but neither `:call append(13, getreg("", 1, 1))` nor `:call append(13, split(@@, "\n"))` look particularly good.